# Using matlab example for regression

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, regression, counting, feature-extraction

I am trying to learn DL with an example. However, running the following code results in an error

```
imds = imageDatastore(fullfile(rootFolder),'Labels',lab.labels35_16);
imds.ReadFcn = @(filename)readAndPreprocessImage(filename);    
[trainingSet, testSet] = splitEachLabel(imds, 0.3, 'randomize');
trainingFeatures = activations(convnet, trainingSet, featureLayer, ...
    'MiniBatchSize', 32, 'OutputAs', 'columns');
```

sAnd the error is Undefined function 'categories' for input arguments of type 'double'. I understand that categories in he original example is string based labels. But mine is int values. 
Not sure why it isn't working. Kindly help[image: Error follow up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [catogories](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categories.html), it seems like the input needs to be a [categorical](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html). You might have to do categories(categorical()).

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, but rather copy relevant excerpts to the page. If either page is moved or deleted, the links and answer are of little use.